# d3 is not defined - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, d3.js, referenceerror, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to use a "fancy graph" found at http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426:

[image]

The way I've done it was to download the code and simply edit the CSV file to match my data. Then I simply open the .html-file in Firefox to see the interactive graph. However, using it at a another computer I get the following errors:

ReferenceError: d3 is not defined sequences.js:25

ReferenceError: d3 is not defined index.html:28

As I have almost no knowledge of d3 or javascript I am a bit lost.
Can any of you give me a hint to what is causing the errors and how I should correct the code?

I've done a single alteration to the code making it the following:

**Javascript:**

```
// Dimensions of sunburst.
var width = 750;
var height = 600;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// Mapping of step names to colors.
var colors = {
  "G0": "#5687d1",
  "G1": "#5c7b61",
  "G2": "#de783b",
  "G3": "#6ab975",
  "G4": "#a173d1",
  "G5": "#72d1a1",
  "Afgang": "#615c7b"
};

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0; 

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

// Use d3.text and d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
// row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.
d3.text("sequences.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  drawLegend();
  d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

  nodes = nodes.filter(function(d) {
      return (d.name != "end"); // BJF: Do not show the "end" markings.
      });


  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover);

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 };

// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {

  var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
  var percentageString = percentage + "%";
  if (percentage < 0.1) {
    percentageString = "< 0.1%";
  }

  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(percentageString);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });


  d3.select("#explanation")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", d3.keys(colors).length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.entries(colors))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
}

function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}

// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how 
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flow for G1 customers</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sequences.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="sequence"></div>
      <div id="chart">
        <div id="explanation" style="visibility: hidden;">
          <span id="percentage"></span><br/>
          of G1 customers follow this flow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <input type="checkbox" id="togglelegend"> Legend<br/>
      <div id="legend" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sequences.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Hack to make this example display correctly in an iframe on bl.ocks.org
      d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "700px");
  </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error indicates that including the D3 library wasn't successful. It looks like you're including it in your script though, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Do you get any other error messages?

Comment: No other errors, sadly. My other computer has some kinda strict security settings, could that cause the issue? Is it possible to include the library by having it in the same folder or a similar way that would not be bothered by security settings?

Comment: It's possible that it can't download it. You could download the D3 script, put it in the same folder and adjust the path in your source.

Comment: Thank you, that works! It only seems to work in Firefox, but that is not an issue :) Feel free to answer my question to close the thread.

Comment: may I know how you have captured and generated the `gif` please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There may be security restrictions that prevent your browser from downloading the D3 script. What you can do is to download the scripts, place them in the same folder as your files, and change the referenced paths in your source.

Answer (score 50):

Had the same issue, though I initially thought it is because of security restrictions of browser, that wasn't the case. It worked when I added the charset to the script tag as shown below:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The same is shown in the d3 docs, though it doesn't mention this issue specifically: http://d3js.org/

Yes, having it locally works too.

```
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the full example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3 tutorial</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!--<script src="d3.min.js"></script>-->
</head> 
<body>
    <script>
        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 500);
        var circle = canvas.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx",250)
                        .attr("cy", 250)
                        .attr("r", 50)
                        .attr("fill", "red");
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Quite interestingly, once it works, it seem to work there onwards even if the charset is removed (yes, cleared cache). Also initially it wasn't working on both Firefox and Chrome!

Comment: In my case, I only had to add the "http:" which was missing from the online example source, then it worked in Firefox. Concretely, I replaced `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`
 with  `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: `charset="utf-8"` works for me too. @Bobz, can you tell why?

Answer (score 14):

You may also need to add:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

to your head section

Comment: totally worked in my case. Latin encoding didn't so characters didnt work well. THanks.

Answer (score 6):

in case browser does not prevent it from downloading and still getting the error, d3.js should be placed before jquery.

Comment: future readers should be aware that even this can cause a very much similar error. +1

Answer (score 3):

I just moved my reference to the package as the first import in my head tag:

```
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
...
...
</head>
```

Seemed to work for me

Answer (score 2):

Replace <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> with <meta charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a `grunt build` to get get rid of this error.  (Using Yeoman and Ember.js.)

Answer (score 1):

And for JavaScript noobs like me - problem could be that you don't import it correctly. Try reading [import docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and things like:

`import * as d3 from 'd3-transition'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio you can go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> IntelliSense and check the box "Download remote references". That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: there is now a [`d3-webpack-loader` package](https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-webpack-loader) which makes it easy to load d3 in webpack. I am not the creator of the package, I've only used it to see if it works. Here's a quick example.

```
// Install the loader
npm install --save d3-webpack-loader

// Install the d3 microservices you need
npm install --save d3-color
npm install --save d3-selection
```

In our `entry.js` file we'll require `d3` using the `d3-webpack-loader` with:

```
const d3 = require('d3!');
```

and can then use some of the `d3` methods with:

```
d3.selectAll("p").style("color", d3.color("red").darker());
```

Answer (score 0):

Super late to this response but **none** of the above solutions worked out for me. I found a fix though!

I am on macOS Catalina. For some bizarre reason, it turned out to be a decompression/unpack issue with the .tgz file from Observable's website. I use an application called The Unarchiver to decompress files, but in this case, the .tgz file did not properly unpack. There was a folder and file missing compared to a friend's computer not using the same program.

**Solution**: I unpacked .tgz without a third party program – just used macOS (simply double clicking on the file). Then, I loaded the page locally and it worked!

If double clicking on the file fails to unpack, try running `tar -xzf filename.tgz` in Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are importing the d3 from online.
In your HTML, make sure that you are importing the d3 before connecting your JavaScript file.

```
// Importing D3.js
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>

// Importing D3-Scale   
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>

// Connecting my JS file
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: This question is asked about 9 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.