# no graph output for d3.js

Tags: javascript, php, graph, d3.js, wamp

http://jsfiddle.net/amanminhas16/KUf7f/

```
var root = {
    "name"    : "Total Number Of Users",
    "size"    : 50000,
    "children": [{
        "name":"user A"
    },
    {
        "name":"user B"
    },
    {
        "name":"user C"
    },
    {
        "name":"user D"
    },
      ]
};
```

this was inspired by

http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/YMa2y/

But even if i get the exact code, i do not get a graph output.
If i copy my code into his jsfiddle, it gives me my desired result. can you tell me what could be the issue ?

i am using WAMP + Zend.

Thank you in adv.

Comment: For one thing, you need to add D3 to the fiddle...dropbox on left titled Frameworks & Extensions...pick D3.

Comment: FernOfTheAndes. Great, that worked, but still it does not work on my localhost. :-/ . the exact same code, copy pasted with this additional line : <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined tree:472
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I thought this err would go away with this :<script src="d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"; charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: try with the http protocol added: `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"; charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: That did not work either, i read online that may be chrome has a problem with the http and https, i tried both, none worked. I also tried on mozilla firefox. but no success there either.

Comment: In the meantime, you could resort to downloading D3 to your machine and just pointing to the local copy.

Comment: Also I found this online <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381097/d3-is-not-defined-referenceerror> . But the solution they came up with was to download the zip file. I would rather not do that and use the CDN in an effective way. :/

Comment: d3 is defined now, when i type d3 in console it gives me : Object {version: "3.4.2", ascending: function, descending: function, min: function, max: function…}. 
But now  : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'.
All i did is remove charsef = "utf-8"

Comment: I have not yet used version 3.4.2. But not having the utf-8 has created problems in the past, particularly with the non-minimized version. See [this useful entry](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195).

Comment: May b i could use an older version, where can i find the CDN for it if you know. 
Also i find this very strange that the same code works in jsfiddle but not on my machine :/ aah..

Comment: but at the moment the error im trying to fight is this one :
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Comment: FernOfTheAndes - You were much help, I cannot thank you enough.
I found the solution. I just had to place my js code within $(document).ready(dunction(){ // here })
.:D .Thank you again my friend.

Comment: Ah...an unsuspecting reason, as it can often happen. Re. help, YMW :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

But actually, The problem was that i did not put my javascript code in

`$(document).ready(function(){//here})`

It works great now :) ..

Thank you Christopher and FernOfTheAndes for all the help

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#wiki-installing) page explains quite well how to setup d3 in your localhost.

You have to:

- include d3.js in your page using: 
  `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`
- start a python server if you want to access local files using: 
  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`

Comment: Hi Christopher, Thanks a lot for your suggestion.