# ReferenceError: d3 is not defined using web-maker

Tags: d3.js, web-maker

I followed this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381097/d3-is-not-defined-referenceerror), entering the complete code into the HTML pane of [web-maker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-maker/lkfkkhfhhdkiemehlpkgjeojomhpccnh?hl=en):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3 tutorial</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!--<script src="d3.min.js"></script>-->
</head> 
<body>
    <script>
        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 500);
        var circle = canvas.append("circle")
                        .attr("cx",250)
                        .attr("cy", 250)
                        .attr("r", 50)
                        .attr("fill", "red");
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

That results in an empty page.

The I moved the script "content" to the JS pane, that results in "ReferenceError: d3 is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script content will move to the **JS** pane. But the external scripts need to be loaded through the "Add library" button. In the "Add library" box, simply select D3 from the list of popular libraries.

[image]