# ReferenceError - d3 is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[1]https://gist.github.com/anilnairxyz/754723d31dd14d50a3142e65d47c1057

I just tested it before changing the code

I copied the code and simply changed the .html-file

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

then I get the following errors:

ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

As I have almost no knowledge of d3 or javascript.

Can anyone give me a hint to what is causing the errors and how I should correct the code please?

I've already seen this post and tried
[d3 is not defined - ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381097/d3-is-not-defined-referenceerror)

Comment: You are using an old version of d3. A lot of d3 functions changed between v3 and v4. Can you post some of your js?

Comment: @rguttersohn I didn't change anything except the html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error screenshot, it seems you're executing `heatmap.js` in a console with node.js. The issue is that the `heatmap.js` script, and the other scripts of the project, are designed to be executed in a browser with an HTML page, and not in isolation in a node terminal. To run a D3 project you need a local web server, and then access the localhost:{port number} on the browser. [Here is a tutorial on how to do it with with node.js](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server)